# Is it possible to rephrase "we're going to bring back that hulking hunk of bumbling brawn"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

The context of the following quote is from the comic book Avengers.  In a circus, the ringmaster introduces a brawny guy by saying:

> First off today, we're going to bring back that hulking hunk of bumbling brawn you've all been waiting for.

I would like to translate this sentence to Portuguese, but I was not able. It is extremely difficult to translate *hulking hunk of bumbling brawn*. I asked it [here](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/english_to_portuguese/poetry_literature/4489324-hulking_hunk_of_bumbling_brawn.html). Is it possible to rephrase that sentence without losing the meaning of it?

Comment: @Roy's answer is right on.  But a rephrase in English might be: monstrous mass of menial muscle.

Comment: Doesn't "menial" kind of have connotations of "small", not "clumsy"?

Comment: @Bidella, I struggled with an *m-word* for bumbling. Since one of the meanings of 'bumble' is drone and drones do menial labor, I went with it.  In my mind menial has to do with servants and typically your 'bumbling brawn' is going to be acting in some sort of subservient role.

Comment: @Jim: "Monstrous mass of maladroit muscle"

Comment: @J.R.:  *Nice one*!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe a similar meaning would be carried by chosing your phrase in the target language using words that alliterate (sound similar / begin with similar sounds, or at least rhyme) and describes large size and clumsy strength.

Comment: Roy nailed it.  In fact, I'd even say that if you translate the sentence, and the result has no alliteration, then you _would_ have lost some of the original message.  It is very intentionally alliterative.

Comment: Given that the source of the quote is from The Avengers, I would guess that you'd want to base the alliteration off whatever the Hulk's translated name is.

Comment: @SarekOfVulcan: It is an old comic book from '80s. The character is Wonder Man. By the way, we do not translate Hulk to Portuguese (in Brazil). It is translated as O Incrível Hulk.